# Modify iPhone restrictions passcode

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to change the restrictions passcode on an iPhone without restoring the phone? I haven't forgotten the passocde; I just want to change it.

Comment: So... if you know it, then why not change it in `Settings`?

Comment: I did not see an option in Settings to change the restrictions passcode. (I'm not talking about the lock screen passcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erasing the phone in iTunes will remove the restrictions along with everything else.

Per my comment, you can change the passcode for restrictions under `Settings > General > Restrictions`

By clicking **[enable restrictions]** it will prompt you for password, you may disable it and then re-enter the passcode.

Reference as well here:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2478010?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Specifically, it's annoying because disabling restrictions entirely clears every last restriction that is set.  It took me an hour to figure out what we needed and will take at least 10 minutes to re-enter them with the new restrictions passcode.

Comment: BEFORE resetting your passcode, I highly recommend taking screenshots of your current restriction settings.  This is particularly important if you, like me, have a long list of specific websites that you've restricted.  I'd add this as a separate answer, but I don't have privileges here, and this is a really annoying aspect of the iOS.  @AndrewWolfe

Comment: HIGHLY recommend emailing yourself the screenshots from the previous comment, so that after resetting the code, you can refer to them on a separate device screen and not have to continuously toggle back and forth to your images in order to add each item from the list.

Comment: totally agree @PaulPettengill

Answer (score 3):

From [Techtips at salon.com](http://techtips.salon.com/change-parental-controls-pin-iphone-4755.html):

1. Open the "Settings" menu from your Home screen, and then tap the "General" button.
2. Select "Restrictions" from the General page when it loads to the screen. A page loads prompting you for a passcode.
3. Enter the current PIN into the prompt. The iPhone will grant you access to the Restrictions preferences page.
4. Tap "Disable Restrictions" at the top of the References screen. The passcode prompt appears again.
5. Enter the current PIN. iPhone returns you to the Restrictions page.
6. Tap the "Enable Restrictions" button at the top of the page. Enter a new PIN into the passcode prompt when it appears on your screen. Confirm the PIN in the "Re-enter Your Restrictions Passcode" prompt to finalize the change.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We prefer answers which stand on their own and do not rely on off-site pages. Links may break rendering your answer useless. I've included the relevant parts directly in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go on restrictions on setting (general) and enter your current PIN then at the top it says 'disable restrictions' and there it goes!!